# Wordpress: How to remove pages from search results

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I've got a Wordpress based website and I'd just like to remove pages from search results. Of course I can't just do something like `if( is_page() ) { // don't do anything; }` because it would still count as a result and so it would affect pagination etc...

So, maybe some parameter in the search query? But the thing is, the search query is written in the wordpress core so I can just edit it?

Comment: As far as I'm aware you can't control this. What you put online is there to be indexed. WordPress does have the future to discourage search engines from indexing, but that's not just for one page nor certain it will work fully.

Comment: I meant exluded from internal search, because I only want the user to search for posts and not for pages like the "Contact us" page... and I thought it was a common issue for beginners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean from the internal wordpress search, there are some plugins that allow you to set a page or article as excluded from search result.
You could try this one:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-exclude/

If you also wan't to exclude the page from the Search engines, you should also add the url of the page to the robots.txt file in your wordpress folder.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact problem, and I found this piece from [John Parris](https://www.johnparris.com/exclude-certain-pages-from-wordpress-search-results/) that solved it.

```
function jp_search_filter( $query ) {
  if ( ! $query->is_admin && $query->is_search && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $query->set( 'post__not_in', array( 10,11,20,105 ) );
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'jp_search_filter' );
```

You can, of course, use a plugin as well. I just had specific need to remove only two products from search and *not* have them private.